Is it even possible to auto connect user wallet
We have two dApps one is on domain https://domain.com and the other is on https://sub.domain.com; Very basic apps which are utilizing Blocknative @web3-onbord; So is it even possible when a user has been connected to our dApp (lets say with some metamask wallet) on some kind of redirect to transfer that data from one domain to another and to skip the whole connection process and further more is this a possible security issue?

It's unlikely it is unsupported, due to security issues as I say. It would just makes wallet overly complex for very niche use case.
